# How Can I change the background color of a text on a Console Application C#

Tags: c#, console-application

I am writing a small console application in c# and I want to use the arrow keys to navigate through my menu. To make the selected option visible to the user I want to highlight it with a white background and black text but only the word and not the whole line.

I tried to position the cursor at the beginning of the word so only the word would be highlighted but it did not work. Could someone put me on the right direction, please?

```
for (int i = 0; i < filesArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();

            if (i == 0)
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                Program.WriteAtTheMiddleOfTheScreen(filesArray[0]);
                Console.ResetColor();
            }
            else
            {

                Program.WriteAtTheMiddleOfTheScreen(filesArray[i]);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Program.WriteAtTheMiddleOfTheScreen("Exit Program");

        Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.WindowWidth/2)-filesArray[0].Length+2, 2);
```

[That is what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RgQL.png)

[That is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqUts.png)

```
public static void WriteAtTheMiddleOfTheScreen(string message)
    {
        message = String.Format("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth / 2) +    (message.Length / 2)) + "}", message);
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
```

Comment: see this: https://www.dotnetperls.com/console-color

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code i wrote to change the color actually works but it changes the whole line until the end of the string. What I actually need is to change only the background of the string as it looks on the picture I uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            string Text = "MAP" + i;
            Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.WindowWidth - Text.Length) / 2, Console.CursorTop);
            if (i == 0)
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;                    
                Console.WriteLine(Text);
                Console.ResetColor();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Text);
            }
        }
```

See [image: result]

Comment: Thank you!!!

My problem was because I had a method that writes everything in the middle of the console screen. I changed my output and instead of

[Program.WriteAtTheMiddleOfTheScreen(filesArray[i]);]

I did 

[Console.WriteLine(filesArray[i]);]

Your answer gave me the light I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The `Console` class supports two properties called `ForegroundColor` and `BackgroundColor`.

See [MSDN: System.Console.ForegroundColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor(v=vs.110).aspx) and [MSDN: System.Console.BackgroundColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.backgroundcolor(v=vs.110).aspx)

<sup>(Hint: using Microsoft Visual Studio, you can place the cursor on `Console` and hit Ctrl+Space to get a list of all properties offered by `Console`.)</sup>

You can set these properties using members of the `System.ConsoleColor` enumeration which contains members such as `White`, `Blue`, etc.

See [MSDN: System.ConsoleColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecolor(v=vs.110).aspx)

So, you set the `BackgroundColor` property to some color, do your `System.Console.Write()`, then set `BackgroundColor` to something else, and so on.

Keep in mind that spaces are painted with the background color, so to prevent areas of the screen from being painted with unwanted background color, refrain from setting the `BackgroundColor` property to an unwanted value and writing spaces there.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I can actually change the color of text and background but not the way I would like. I edited my question and posted two pictures: One show how it should look like and the other how it actually looks like.

Thanks for the ctrl+space tip, it helped me now with other things and will be useful in the future.

Comment: You might want to show how you have implemented that `Program.WriteAtTheMiddleOfTheScreen()` method.

Comment: I updated the question and included the method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[C# Console Color Tutorial](https://www.dotnetperls.com/console-color)
This page has all you need to change the color of console application.

```
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.WriteLine("White on blue.");
    Console.WriteLine("Another line.");
```

The above code will change the background and foreground color of the console.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Also, your link is broken.